# Add script action for buttons in html with Vapor

Tags: html, swift, vapor, leaf

I am developing a web app with Swift 4 and Vapor 2.0. I have a method for a `POST` request which creates a new user:

```
builder.post("user", "createUser") { (request) -> ResponseRepresentable in
```

But I don't know how to add action for button in the `.leaf` file to call the `createUser` method. It easy to add a JavaScript action in a `.html` file, like that `<script  src="js/index.js"></script>`. But with Vapor, I didn't see any mention about that in the [Vapor 2.0 docs](https://docs.vapor.codes/2.0/)

**Update:**

With help from @Caleb Kleveter, now it worked. I updated `html` page(it's just for test, so that it's not a nice page) with hope: it'll help for newcomer whom face with the same problem when use `vapor`.

Here is my HTML contents:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html >
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
            <title>Responsive Login Form</title>


            <link rel='stylesheet prefetch' href='http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.2/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css'>

                <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles/app.css">


                </head>

                <body>
                <link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Ubuntu:500' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
                <h3>
                <form action="/user/createUser" method="POST" class="login-form">
                <label for="username">Username:</label>
                <input type="text" placeholder="Username" name="username"/>
                <label for="password">Password:</label>
                <input type="password" placeholder="Password" name="password"/>
                <input type="submit" value="Login" class="login-button"/>
                <form>
                </h3>
                <a class="sign-up">Sign Up!</a>
                <br>
                <h6 class="no-access">Can't access your account?</h6>
                </div>
                </div>
                <!-- <div class="error-page">
                    <div class="try-again">Error: Try again?</div>
                </div> -->
                <script src='http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js'></script>
                    <script src='http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.2/jquery-ui.min.js'></script>

                    <script  src="js/index.js"></script>

            </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Scripts can be added to a `.leaf` file the same way as you would in HTML, just add a script tag:

```
<script src="js/index.js"></script>
```

From viewing your code, what you want is a `form` to post the data to the server. You should replace your `.login-form` `div` with a `form` element:

```
<form action="/create-user" method="POST" class="login-form">
    <label for="username">Username:</label>
    <input type="text" placeholder="Username" name="username"/>
    <label for="password">Password:</label>
    <input type="password" placeholder="Password" name="password"/>
    <input type="submit" value="Login" class="login-button"/>
<form>
<a class="sign-up">Sign Up!</a>
<h6 class="no-access">Can't access your account?</h6>
```

[Here is the documentation](http://devdocs.io/html/element/form) for HTML forms.

Then you should be able to access the form data in you route method with `request.body`:

```
func createUser(req: Request) throws -> ResponseRepresentable {
    guard let password = req.body["password"]?.string,
          let username = req.body["username"]?.string else {
             throw Abort.badRequest
    }

    // The rest of your code goes here
}
```

I am not sure if this will work, I haven't tested it, but I think you get the idea.